# Android - Splash screen handling - Animation and Remote call together with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I am newbie in RxJava / RxAndroid universe. I am trying to achieve following scenario.

I have a SplashActivity which shows an animation for a second and then it launches another activity (based on whether a user is signed in or not). I want this Splash screen to perform additional task of sending some information to my remote server. The logic to implement is the activity should begin showing animation when it shows up and also do a remote request call which can either complete with a success or any other error (like ConnectionTimeout).

**Conditions:**

If the remote call finishes before the animation completes, it should wait to get animation complete and then continue to next screen.

If the remote call not completing before the animation, the Splash screen will continue to show up.

These are the ingredients we have:

1. An animationCompletable

```
    private Completable animationCompletable() {
        return Completable.create(emitter -> {
            ScaleAnimation fade_in = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            fade_in.setDuration(1000);
            fade_in.setFillAfter(true);
            imgLogo.startAnimation(fade_in);
            fade_in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            emitter.setCancellable(fade_in::cancel);
        });
    }
```

2. A Single clientUpdateCall

```
// apiService is a retrofit interface for making call to remote webservice
Single<ResponseBody> clientUpdateCall = apiService.put(id, remoteInfo);
```

How to proceed from this point? What are the combine methods suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have two Observable one for animation and another one for network result.
Each one has its dependent results but we want get both results at same time(sync results).
For this scenario you should use Combining Observable.

Read more:

https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-rxjava-in-android-operators-for-combining-observables-25734080f4be

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `concat` to link the two observables together.

Firstly convert the Single to Completable so that you can concat with the animation Completable,

```
        Completable apiCompletable = Completable.fromSingle(clientUpdateCall);
```

and then you `concat` them together,

```
animationCompletable().concatWith(apiCompletable).doOnComplete( () -> {
   //go main activity
});
```